# Combing MySQL Rows With Same ID PHP

Tags: php, mysql, grouping

I have a table "orders" which saves all the orders made on a website. It saves the data in the following way:

```
ID | Session_id | image | item | extra | customer_name
```

Sample date

```
 12 | sdgfafjhsf | image1.jpg | coffee | milk | roger
 13 | sdgfafjhsf | image1.jpg | muffin | jam  | roger
 14 | fjgjgsdfjg | image3.jpg | coffee | none | John
```

Currently I have the PHP accessing the database and spitting out all of the listings one by one.

```
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("store") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Retrieves data from MySQL 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status ='ordered'") or die(mysql_error());  //Puts it into an array 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 

 //Outputs the image and other data

 Echo "$info[customer_name] <img src='cameras/$info[image]'/>  : $info[item] with $info[extras] <br />"; 


 }
```

I am ideally wanting the data to group by the session ID. So it prints out the name of the customer and the image once and then all of the items associated with it.

eg. Roger , coffee, milk, muffin, jam

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You can use group_concat.
"SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(item) AS items, GROUP_CONCAT(extra) AS extras FROM orders WHERE status ='ordered' GROUP BY Session_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to order the SQL so that you get all entries from each session following each other, and just remember the last session id you fetched to tell if you should output the name and picture or not; here's some pseudo code to show what I mean;

```
$data = 
  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status ='ordered' ORDER BY session_id")
                or die(mysql_error());

$last_session_id = "**DUMMY**";  // Set a dummy value to not match the first row

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
  if($info['session_id'] != $last_session_id) 
  {
    //Outputs the image and other data if a new session_id has been found
    echo "$info[customer_name] <img src='cameras/$info[image]'/>  : $info[item] with $info[extras] <br />"; 
    $last_session_id = $info['session_id'];
  } else {
    // Same session_id as last row, skip name and picture
    echo "$info[item] with $info[extras] <br />"; 
  }
}
```

As a side note, the `mysql_*` database API is deprecated, you should look into using `mysqli` or `pdo` instead.

Answer (score 0):

well try this..

```
 SELECT Session_id,image,item,extra,customer_name FROM orders WHERE status='ordered' group by Session_id,image,item,extra,customer_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to run two separate query. In first query you have to find all distinct customer name, better if you use customer id rather than customer name because id cannot be duplicate. Then after getting all customer who have ordered item, iterate them in loop and inside loop run another query to retrieve all orders of that customer by again customer id or by customer name.

Answer (score 0):

In you `while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))`-loop, where you print the output, you could add it to a [standard array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) where the keys are the Session_ids.

Then you call `echo $foo['sdgfafjhsf']` to get an array with db-entries which you can  enumerate through print accordingly.